# Cargar input en base a otro input C# MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo la siguiente duda de que manera puedo cargar un input en base a otro, en esta ocasion es introduciendo el numero empleado quiero que me llene un input con el id correspondiente, en PHP yo uso Jquery, en C# voy empezano no se si es de la misma manera, les dejo la estructura de mi proyecto.

Tabla **registros**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla ***Empleados***.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Busco que en el siguiente formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ingresar el numero de empleado "80717" me cargue el ID de dicho empleado que en este caso seria "1".

**HomeController:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Cafeteria.Data;
using Cafeteria.Models;

namespace Cafeteria.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly CafeteriaDbContext _context;

        public HomeController(CafeteriaDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Home
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            // Variable de inicio de dia actual
            var StartDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() + " 07:00:00");
            // Final del dia siguiente
            var EndDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString() + " 07:00:00");

            var cafeteriaDbContext = _context.registros.Include(r => r.Empleados)
                                           .Where(b => b.FechaRegistro >= StartDate
                                            && b.FechaRegistro <= EndDate)
                                           .OrderByDescending(b => b.FechaRegistro);

            return View(await cafeteriaDbContext.ToListAsync());
        }

        // POST: /Index
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index([Bind("id,FechaRegistro,TurnoComida,Empleadosid")] registros registros)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(registros);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            
            return View(registros);
        }

        private bool registrosExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.registros.Any(e => e.id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

**Formulario:**

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Index">
                <div class="form-group">
                    //// Input para ingresar Numero de empleado **80717** ///
                    <input name="Empleadosid" class="form-control" autofocus="" required=""/>
                    //// Input destinado para cargar Id de empleado **80717** ///
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="idEmployee" placeholder="ID EMPLEADO" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="FechaRegistro" id="InputHora" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="TurnoComida" id="InpuTurno" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-2" style="float: right;" />
                </div>
</form>
```

El motivo por el que no ingreso directamente el ID del empleado es por que ya existe un codigo de barras con los numeros de empleados.

Espero me puedas orientar un poco con esta duda.

**Edicion:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#NumEmpleadoSearch').change(function (e) {
                var url = "Home/BuscarIdEmpleado?IdEmpleado=" + $('#NumEmpleadoSearch').val();
                e.preventDefault();
 
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",                                              
                    url: url,                            
                    data: null,                                               
                                                                               
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",            
                    dataType: "json",                                         
                    async: true,                                               
                    success: function (resultado) {                            
                        var num = resultado.empleados.id;
                        $('#lblResultado').val(num);
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                        var error = eval("(" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ")");
                        aler(error.Message);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult BuscarIdEmpleado(int IdEmpleado)    // el método debe ser de static
        {
            var EmpleadoId = _context.registros.Include(r => r.Empleados)
                                                .Where(b => b.Empleados.id == IdEmpleado)
                                                .FirstOrDefault();
            return Json(EmpleadoId);
        }
```

Ya estoy obteniendo la informacion del empleado de acuerdo al id, pero no logro llenar el input en este caso lo puse como ejemplo con un label pero no me pasa el dato a la variable me la deja "undifined"

GET:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi tengo el form:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Index">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="NumEmpleadoSearch" id="NumEmpleadoSearch" class="form-control" required=""/>
                    <input name="Empleadosid" class="form-control" autofocus="" required=""/>
                    <label id="lblResultado" name="lblResultado"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="FechaRegistro" id="InputHora" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="TurnoComida" id="InpuTurno" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mt-2" style="float: right;" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Qué has intentado?

Comment: Ya puedo obtener la informacion por el GET con json pero no logro jalar el dato id al input o label, te deje actualizacion en mi POST

Comment: @Arriel Ya logre cargar el Id del empleado. solo actualice el Script(ya actualice), pero tengo un problema, como el input esta dentro del form me da un error al hacer el POST, ya que ese dato no lo guardo solo es para obtener el "id" si lo saco del form todo queda funcionando, pero como me interesa que al dar enter se envie el form tengo ese problema

Comment: `public JsonResult BuscarIdEmpleado(int IdEmpleado)` ese IdEmpleado, reemplazadalo por simplemente `Id`. Intenta nuevamente.